# Display item in column - Datatables

Tags: laravel, datatables

I am tyring to display this under my status column on my datatables but the text doesn't appear neither am i getting any syntax error. What am i not doing right?

```
  public function getStatus()
     {

        $items = Item::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();

        return Datatables::of($items)->addColumn('status', function ($item) {
         '<p>

@if ($item->status == 0)
<span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-success">Accepted</span>

@else ($item->status == 1)
<span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-danger">Pending</span>
              </p>';

        })->make(true);      
     }
```

Comment: did you get your collections?? check dd($items)

Comment: yes i  get my collection. i am able to see that in my network as well @Sohel0415

Comment: did you try passing a single object?? like $item = Item::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->first();

Comment: @Sohel0415 do you please understand my question? :)

Comment: that's what i am trying, from where did you call this function??

Comment: you are learning laravel in the wrong way.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi why do you say so?